# jqGrid 'selarrrow' returning row numbers instead of row IDs

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, multi-select

I can see from the jqGrid JSON data being posted to the browser that the row ID (denoted by "i" in the JSON row data) is coming through correctly, but when I make a selection and check the `$('#list').getGridParam('selarrrow')` it is showing the selected **row numbers** as opposed to their IDs.

Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Below is a picture of the JSON result (copy and paste not really an option)

[(bigger version of the image here)](http://i31.tinypic.com/25qwufd.png)

[image: JSON Result]

And the javascript code to check the selection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkSelection(){
        alert($('#list').getGridParam('selarrrow').join());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post your test JSON data and the JavaScript code example (especially jsonReader used).

Comment: Sorry Jimbo, but I can not reproduce your problem with data and code which you posted. Look at for example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GetScheduledReleases.txt and http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GetScheduledReleases.htm. If you post a part of your JSON data (some rows only) and the code (can be a simplified) of your jqGrid declaration one will be able to reproduce your problem without having Server components running. Then one could find a solution of your problem.

Comment: I suppose that IDs which be send from the server are ignored and so row numbers will be the real row ids. You can verify this with `getDataIDs` method inside of `loadComplete` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Justin and Oleg - Im certain that you were put on this planet to solve the world's jQueries :) Thanks again for your assistance with this problem.

**SOLUTION**
In my code, the grid's column definitions didnt specify a `key` column from which to draw each row's ID from - how it was getting the `i = <id>` in the screenshot above, I have no idea, but it definitely wasn't using that ID for each row. I changed the grid definition to the following:

```
...,
colNames: ['ID', 'Family', 'Variety', 'Type', 'EDI #', 'Colour', 'Swatch'],
colModel: [{ name: 'id', index: 'id', key: true, hidden: true },
...
```

(notice the `key: true` in the colModel for the ID column)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? According to the [jqGrid documentation for selarrrow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> This options is read only. Determines the currently selected rows when multiselect is set to true. This is one dimensional array and the values in the array correspond to the selected id's in the grid.

So if it is returning row numbers there is a bug in the jqGrid API. Would it be possible for you to post more information, such as the result of your call to `selarrrow` as well as a full listing of the ID's in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that IDs which be send from the server are ignored and so row numbers will be the real row ids. You can verify this with `getDataIDs` method inside of `loadComplete` event. Why the IDs will be ignored I could say only if your post more information.